# backup capacitive touch button with momentary switch

Tags: arduino

I would like to plug a capacitive touch button on an arduino input and a momentary push button on the same input.

Any suggestion ?

The touch button spec : https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ttp223-datasheet.pdf
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pin 12 "OPDO" is an open-drain output, wire the mechanical button in paralell with pin12 and ground and configure your auduino input with the pull-up enabled.

In the BA6 package it doesn't have the "OPDO" terminal, you could connect the switch  (and a pull up or down)  to the AHLB input. that should result in the switch causing the output to switch states when activated.

Another option would be to use a dual-throw switch between the touch output and the device input allowing the switch to override the touch output. or a switch and a gate could be used for much the same effect.

Comment: thanks but I was not enough accurate. 

The IC is packaged in a BA6 box and I'm not sure it's a OPDO output.
Spec says has no option, but do not clearly states if it's an open-drain output by default.

Comment: BA6 is harder, it doesn't hve the oped drain output... maybe the AHLB inout could be used for the switch.