# SSR controllable by independent touch button (TTP223) and I/O for Micro-controller

Tags: solid-state-relay

I am looking to solve the following problem.
I want to drive an optocoupler, which will drive a triac, and I want the following to hold.

1. I can toggle the state of the optocoupler input via a momentary output of a TTP223 capacitative module.
2. I can also set/reset or read the state of the optocoupler input via a microcontroller gpio pin.

Further information:
Following the approach provided by Swagatam (https://www.homemade-circuits.com/build-these-simple-flip-flop-circuits/?unapproved=88094&moderation-hash=b2e33d4d54dc810e6d71964c0ac3e91e - Schematic 4)
Here is my [modified schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X40TilP1LoIQ9KJw_5GLcc9p-T1dhs6v/view?fbclid=IwAR1uo9uzusCCwf0hxftKHrDOMqgc86q-vi3ILTm4yeyJwWCpLatKvy3FNPM)[image: Modified schematic for momentary latch]

The I/O pin from Microcontroller is set with PULL_UP mode. Can you please be so kind to advice me on whether the schematic is correctly made. I replaced the Switch with 2 NPN transistors to mimic the switch action from controlling signal (TTP223 and GPIO from Microcontroller).

With this setting, the optocoupler will still be controllable when Microcontroller is not operational.

Please help to guide me through with thanks

Comment: Yes Math, I took the first part from Swagatam (the UA741) to act as a toggle controll line for the opto and triac (relay part). It was my mistake to name the IC741 as a relay. However, this is my intention to develop a relay that can itself allow a manual touch button and also a GPIO port to interface with Microcontroller.
What am not sure is the replacement of the Switch (SW) with the two transitors (Q2, Q3). I could not figure out whether the current on the SW is changed in direction after each press or not!

Comment: Yes Math, the discussion on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533241/backup-capacitive-touch-button-with-momentary-switch could not help to Microcontroller to know the state of relay (on/or off) due to the fact that TTP223 was configured with port B connected (to help it lock the state on pressing).
If this happened, when TTP223 On, we can not set the relay off with Microcontroller (especially when using a port expander with PCF8574)

Comment: This is important when micocontroller failed so the TTP223 can still be usable to turn on/off the relay.
When Microcontroller is working, TTP223 and microcontroller can controll the relay independently!

Comment: Thank Math for being patient, my requirement is:
1. TTP223 can activate the relay (MOC+triac) independently;
2. Microcontroller can also activate/deactivate relay (MOC+triac) in parallel (If relay was on by TTP223) then Microcontroller can turn it off via GPIO and also notice the state of the relay (MOC+triac).
Please be noted that the IC741 is a mechanism to allow the toggle state of the (MOC+triac).

Comment: I made this one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542113/bta16-snnubless-version-triac-was-killed-with-02-laptop-adapter-please-advice
but I could not get the status of relay. The problem is: I am allow to have only 1 pin (requirement) from Microcontroller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122436/discussion-between-math-keeps-me-busy-and-dng-dinh-ngc).

Answer (score 1):

Before delving into an answer, I want to suggest that you carefully consider *why* you feel you can only use 1 microcontroller GPIO pin. The assumption that you must use only one GPIO pin makes the circuitry external to the microcontroller much more complex. It may be so complex that a simpler solution might be to use a larger microcontroller, or to use an I/O extender, or a second microcontroller. Similarly you should consider *why* you want the relay to be controlled either by a microcontroller *or* by a manual switch. Many solutions to control problems involve a switch providing input to a microcontroller, which uC is the only point of control for the relay. The uC can make its decision to turn the relay on or off depending upon input from the switch. Or it can make a decision based upon other inputs. But the uC remains in control of the relay, and always knows whether the relay is active or not, *because it controls* whether the relay is active or not.

Having explained why another solution may be better, I will turn to the problem of using a single gpio pin to both modify and monitor the state of a circuit node external to the uC.

I think the basis of such a solution must involve something akin to the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwnfjF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea here is that the feedback loop of inverters ("not" gates) form a latch or memory element. When neither the GPIO nor the alternate input is acting upon the feedback loop because the both GPIO and alternate input are in a "high impedance" state, then the inverter loop will maintain it's state. That state can be read by the gpio pin, and the loop can drive something at the output.

However, if the GPIO pin of the uC becomes an output and *drives* the GPIO node, it may bring that node to ground or Vcc. When the GPIO pin becomes hi-impedance again, the circuit will maintain it's state.

The resistors in the loop are *necessary*. They must be of a sufficiently high value that the gpio pin can both a) "win" in the contest between the gpio pin and the output of the inverter which is also trying to control that node, and b) so that the gpio pin is not over-driven in its effort to control the node. They must also be sufficiently larger that the outputs of the inverters are not over-driven. The value of the resistors will depend upon 1) the specific microcontroller, the specific inverters (which should have cmos inputs and outputs and not TTL), and possibly the voltage.

An unavoidable side effect of using those resistors is that if the gpio pin is changing the state of the inverter loop, it must *hold* that state for some time because the inverter input capacitances will take some time to charge. The larger the resistors, the larger the required hold time. Similarly, some set-up time is required before the gpio pin can *read* the state of the inverter loop.

Everything said above applies to the "alternate input" as well.

If the alternate input were fed by another microcontroller, the solution would be near complete. the capacitative switch module could be an input to the microcontroller, and a gpio pin could read from or drive the alternate input (which is inverting obviously).

Something less than another microcontroller that might be a solution involves a combination of an edge triggered D-flip-flop with a tri-state buffered output.
This flip-flop would read the state of the inverter loop somewhere, and upon a logic one coming from the capacitative switch would a) lock in that state, and b) enable the tri-state output so that the alternate-input node gets fed with a state opposite to the one it was in.

It is vital for correct functioning, that the locking of state happen sufficiently prior to the enabling of the tri-state output that there is not hazard or glitch. This could be achieved in a number of ways, such as a delay, or more complex circuitry.

Anyway, that is the basis for a solution that involves only one gpio pin. As can be seen, it is not trivial, and a larger uC, an I/O extender, or a second uC might seem more attractive once the difficulties of the single GPIO pin approach are appreciated.

Would be happy to explain or consider this or other solutions further.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Math for your details explanation. Let consider my case a bit so you would understand why I have to do this.

**A. BACKGROUND:** I was asked to design a home switch to replace the Sino switch set (see attached image) that can be controlled over Wifi to turn on/off different lamp (220VAC) and put them all in wall plate.
[image: Sino Switch].
To do so, I have to replace all switches by TTP223 module so that they are all fit inside the switch hole.
It is required that the new Switch can be controlled over wifi using mobile phone (via Blynk as an example) and also by the TTP223 module. This is especially required when internet is lost or the controller is failed. In Vietnam, this problem happens quite often.

**B. SOLUTION:**
The wall-plate is small in size (55mmx140mmx35mm), It should have power 220VAC/3.3VDC for the module to work and upto 6 control line for up to six AC lamp/ceiling fan.
Therefore, I decided to design a PCB with a separated controller (AC/DC power, ESP32-01S, port expander - PCF8574AT) and 6 outputs to connect with upto 6 relays (that can act as a switch or dimmer if required). The initial control board for 4 outputs (has no PCF8574 port expander) I made as below. It already worked on my home. The onlything that it could not handle is about the relay status as I have not reached a suitable design for the relay (also the main topic for this Long discussion)

[image: Control board]

With this design, we can save the cost with difference choice on number of switch node to replace (Such as 2, 3, 4, 5 of 6 nodes).

With this requirement, design of relay need to be able to accept control signal from ESP8266-01S and at the same time it can act as a standalone device upon failure of the Controller.
That was the reason for me to come up with difference options:
**1. Version 1:** Using 02 SPDT ICs SN74LVC1G3157DBVR to switch between different control lines (similar to the case of staircase switch)
[image: 02 SPDT IC SN74LVC1G3157DBVR]
However, with this option, I have no way to capture the status of the load. Also the TTP223 module must be configured in lock mode (press and stay on until press again)
[image: The first workable version of relay]

This relay does not support monitoring of load state as it has no feedback line for Microcontroller. But it does work without Microcontroller.

**2. Version 2:** Develop an I2C relay: It required an I2C master controller and it has it owned pcf8574 chip on the relay: In this mode, the issue of lacking control I/O is gone but the relay itself could not work alone without master controller.
This is the relay:

[image]

and this is the controller, tested and worked

[image: I2C controller]

**3. Version 3:** - being developed. This will base on the option that is being discussed previously in the original question. With this new option, polling the state of the load is feasible by remembering the initial state of the momentary button. With this option, the TTP223 module do not have to be configured in lock mode.
Also, some further reading today allow me to use NE555 for the push on/push off feature with fewer number of parts.

The ESP8266-01S module is the Microcontroller for the board. It is cheap (1.5 USD) and good for smart home device. (Datasheet can be found here http://www.microchip.ua/wireless/esp01.pdf)[image: ESP8266-01S]

Those are considerations for me to go up with all this problems that waste a lot of your time.
I hope it clear so you will be able to advice me on this difficulties.
Best regard
Dang Dinh Ngoc.

Comment: It is an Esp8266-01S, a tiny chip already with wifi and 4 pins.

Comment: No Math, I use 01 ESP8266-01S as the main controller for one wallplate that can control up to 8 lines via a PCF8574 port Expander. I design in following way:
1. Separate control board that can support up to 8 relays (in fact 6 is the maximum) with connecting rail having 6 connecting points to connect with relay module.
2. On demand relay (plug in if needed).
This is why I want to have the relay to be standalone, and can work without Microcontroller in worse case. Design of relay is the main discussion point for this long chat.

Comment: I see your point and have thought about it. I finally came about with option 2. Making the Relay to be an I2C device (see my main text with new photo). But this has similar problem. The relay can not work alone. The only benefit for this is compact design of the control board! >> only one I2C interface with all relays via a common rail.
With option 2, the overall cost is small as PCF8574 is 0.3 USD in Vietnam.
Anyway, I am very interested a lot more in making the relay to be standalone and can provide feedback to Microcontroller on status of load! I will use NE555 instead of an OpAmp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122525/discussion-between-math-keeps-me-busy-and-dng-dinh-ngc).